Instantiating ONNX Session and Environment and overcoming borrowing error without having to use unsafe pointers
I have been trying to instantiate an ONNX runtime environment and session within a struct that can also contain all of the public methods I need. I have a working solution, however this requires the usage of unsafe memory management approaches, which in my opinion defeats the point of using Arc.
Also I apologise if the code examples, and cargo output are too much, the last time I asked a question on SO about Rust I got heavily downvoted for providing shortened code, and only the error messages as to the cargo compilation output.
Thanks in advance.
See working solution:
use std::sync::Arc;
use anyhow::{Context, Error, Result};
use onnxruntime::{
    environment::Environment, 
    session::Session, 
    tensor::OrtOwnedTensor, 
    GraphOptimizationLevel, 
    LoggingLevel
};
use ndarray_stats::QuantileExt;
// use onnxruntime::ndarray::Array1;
use ndarray::{
    Array,
    s
};


pub struct ModelWrapper {
    environment: Arc<Environment>,
    session: Session<'static>,
}

impl ModelWrapper {
    pub fn new(model_path: String) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let environment = Arc::new(Environment::builder()
            .with_name("phi-1-5")
            .with_log_level(LoggingLevel::Verbose)
            .build()?);

        let environment_ref: &'static Environment = unsafe { &*(Arc::as_ptr(&environment) as *const Environment) };

        let session = environment_ref
            .new_session_builder()?
            .with_optimization_level(GraphOptimizationLevel::All)?
            .with_number_threads(8)?
            .with_model_from_file(model_path)
            .map_err(|e| anyhow::anyhow!(e))?; // Convert OrtError to anyhow::Error

        Ok(Self {
            environment,
            session,
        })
    }

    pub fn prediction(&mut self, tokens: Vec<i64>) -> Result<i64, Error> {
        // Prepare the input tensor
        let input_array = Array::from_shape_vec((1, tokens.len()), tokens.clone())?;
        // Run the session with the input tensor
        let outputs: Vec<OrtOwnedTensor<f32, ndarray::Dim<ndarray::IxDynImpl>>> = self.session.run(vec![input_array])?;
        // let reshaped_output = outputs[0];
        let prediction: i64 = i64::try_from(
            QuantileExt::argmax(
                &outputs[0]
                    .slice(s![.., -1, ..])
                    .into_shape([51200])
                    .unwrap()
            ).context("Argmax failed")?
        ).expect("Conversion to i64 failed");
        // Process the output
        println!("{:?}", prediction);
        Ok(prediction)
    }
}

Can anyone advise on a more memory safe approach?
I've tried a number of approaches, and so far the closest I have got is:
use std::sync::Arc;
use anyhow::{Context, Error, Result};
use onnxruntime::{
    environment::Environment, 
    session::Session, 
    tensor::OrtOwnedTensor, 
    GraphOptimizationLevel, 
    LoggingLevel
};
use ndarray_stats::QuantileExt;
use ndarray::{
    Array,
    s
};

pub struct ModelWrapper {
    environment: Arc<Environment>,
    session: Session<'static>,
}

impl ModelWrapper {
    pub fn new(model_path: String) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let environment = Arc::new(Environment::builder()
            .with_name("phi-1-5")
            .with_log_level(LoggingLevel::Verbose)
            .build()?);

        let session = environment
            .new_session_builder()?
            .with_optimization_level(GraphOptimizationLevel::All)?
            .with_number_threads(8)?
            .with_model_from_file(model_path)
            .map_err(|e| anyhow::anyhow!(e))?; // Convert OrtError to anyhow::Error

        Ok(Self {
            environment,
            session,
        })
    }

    pub fn prediction(&mut self, tokens: Vec<i64>) -> Result<i64, Error> {
        // Prepare the input tensor
        let input_array = Array::from_shape_vec((1, tokens.len()), tokens.clone())?;
        // Run the session with the input tensor
        let outputs: Vec<OrtOwnedTensor<f32, ndarray::Dim<ndarray::IxDynImpl>>> = self.session.run(vec![input_array])?;
        // Process the output
        let prediction: i64 = i64::try_from(
            QuantileExt::argmax(
                &outputs[0]
                    .slice(s![.., -1, ..])
                    .into_shape([51200])
                    .unwrap()
            ).context("Argmax failed")?
        ).expect("Conversion to i64 failed");
        println!("{:?}", prediction);
        Ok(prediction)
    }
}

With the cargo output being:
error[E0597]: `environment` does not live long enough
  --> src\model_components\model_wrapper.rs:28:23
   |
23 |           let environment = Arc::new(Environment::builder()
   |               ----------- binding `environment` declared here
...
28 |           let session = environment
   |                         -^^^^^^^^^^
   |                         |
   |  _______________________borrowed value does not live long enough
   | |
29 | |             .new_session_builder()?
   | |__________________________________- argument requires that `environment` is borrowed for `'static`
...
39 |       }
   |       - `environment` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `environment` because it is borrowed
  --> src\model_components\model_wrapper.rs:36:13
   |
23 |           let environment = Arc::new(Environment::builder()
   |               ----------- binding `environment` declared here
...
28 |           let session = environment
   |                         -----------
   |                         |
   |  _______________________borrow of `environment` occurs here
   | |
29 | |             .new_session_builder()?
   | |__________________________________- argument requires that `environment` is borrowed for `'static`
...
36 |               environment,
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^ move out of `environment` occurs here
   |
help: clone the value to increment its reference count
   |
28 |         let session = environment.clone()
   |                                  ++++++++


This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct Environment is the value and Session is (or contains) a reference to it. Your "working solution" has UB.

You will need to manage the environment and session separately in your code. Arc would probably only be an option if you were in control of the definition of Session.
